# Passing Spaces In GET Through Ajax

Tags: ajax, space

My ajax client code passes a textbox value to the server through ajax. The data in the textbox may contain spaces in it. I have checked that it is working in Firefox.

Should I leave the spaces be as they are, or do I need to code them up on the client side (through js) and decode on the server side for compatibility with all browsers sake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774640/passing-value-including-spaces-on-ajax-call?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. My problem is solved. Admins please mark it as duplicate, or miparnisari, please post the answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace all space with `%20` or you can use `escape` function in JavaScript.

```
escape("your data is here")
```

Rference:- [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)

Comment: Thanks. Works flawlessly.