# only one part of Select box value passed to php page by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have html form and ajax use for submission data to php page. There is one select box which values retrieve from database, options are display correctly and same value assigned to 'Value' attribute as well.  but when passed to php page it shows only only one part of value. Codes are blow.

```
<

form id='add-student'>
    <select name="txt_class" class="form-control" id="txt_class">
                                        <?php
                                        include ('../svr/class-dropdown.php');
                                        while ($row_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1)) {
                                            echo '<option value=' . $row_1['class_name'] . '>' . $row_1['class_name'] . '</option>';
                                        }
                                        ?>                         
                                    </select> 
    </form>
```

Value of $row_1['class_name']==Grade 10,

Ajax submission part

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
            var form_data = $("#add-student").serialize();
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url: "../svr/add-stu-submit.php",

                data: form_data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Successfully Added New Student");
                    window.location = "../htdocs/allocate.php";
                }

            });
```

PHP part

```
if(!isset($_POST['stu_index'])){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Something Went Wrong.Please Try Again ");';
        echo 'window.location = "../htdocs/add-stu.php";';
        echo '</script>';
}  else {
$cur_class=$_POST['txt_class'];
var_dump($cur_class);
}
```

My expected output of var_dump is string(5) "Grade 10", but real output is string(5) "Grade", what is issue of my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774640/passing-value-including-spaces-on-ajax-call   check this.

Comment: best would be to avoid having spaces in your value in first place. Maybe you got a `class_id` available, or maybe replace spaces with '_'.

Comment: @jeff difficult to understand what you say